# How to make flyway AWS S3 locations work?

Tags: amazon-s3, flyway

[Summary]
After I used flyway (v7.5.0 on macOS, brew installed) successfully with local migration files, I tried to use AWS S3 instead for Production but failed to run flyway with weird Java errors.

[Details]
Following the doc [Locations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations) , I copied AWS SDK jar dependencies as much I could to libexec/jars/ folder and run with '-locations="s3:bucket-name-xxx/folder-yyy/"', but failed always with the error below:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/core/exception/SdkClientException
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:84)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.createResourceAndClassProviders(Flyway.java:614)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:498)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:380)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:250)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:159)
```

Here the full debug info: [Flyway S3 locations error](https://gist.github.com/sshi100/b2eb1128e62a0ea6f198f7ea37a0beb6)

Note: that S3 bucket folder has been confirmed readable using AWS cli with the same AWS credentials.

I checked this SdkClientException and confirmed it is inside s3-core-version.jar. Then, I tried different versions of brew installation, but still no luck. Then, I tried on Windows, same error. I tried to run from source code with IDE, NO such error...

Are there anything missing? Any idea to make flyway work with AWS S3? Thanks for help!

Comment: It sounds like that location is not on Flyway's classpath. If you put them inside llyway/lib instead, does that change things?

Comment: @JuliaHayward Other NotFound Exception errors came out, conflict.

According to the doc https://flywaydb.org/documentation/addingToTheClasspath, the libexec/jars is the place for dynamic jars loaded in runtime. With debug (-X), I could see the jars added into /jars

...
DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /usr/local/Cellar/flyway/7.5.0/libexec/jars/servicequotas-2.15.24.jar
...

Comment: /jars should work - are you able to post the full debug log (credentials redacted, of course)?

Comment: @JuliaHayward please find it here: https://gist.github.com/sshi100/b2eb1128e62a0ea6f198f7ea37a0beb6

Comment: @JuliaHayward is there any suggestion further? Thanks!

Comment: I've put the dependency list for S3 into the gist - you almost certainly need to ensure that all of those dependencies are present (it's frustrating that the number is so large).

Comment: @JuliaHayward thank you for update! I tried to put all jars missing there but still get the same error. May I ask if anybody from Flyway team has tried the real command line (rather than maven) with S3 when released? Thanks!

Comment: @StevenShi Hi, so do you resolve the problem?, I'm getting the same error related to S3 location, but I'm running flyway from cmd.